# postgreSQL update from one Table to another based on a ID match

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, inner-join

I have a database with `sites` and `counties`. Every site is located in one county. In the `sites` table, the county is already mentioned but I want to replace it with the `ID`, which in is the other table.

My update code is as follows:

```
UPDATE sites
SET cgid = c.gid 
FROM (select c.gid as a from counties c
INNER JOIN sites s
ON c.name = s.county) p;
```

The table `sites` is updated, although every value in the `cgid` column is the same (the ID of the first county). What can I do to get the right values?

Comment: What do you mean with "whole array"?  is your `cgid` column an `array`? Or the `name` or `county` columns?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The target table of an `update` statement should never be repeated in the `from` clause

So I think you want this:

```
UPDATE sites s
  SET cgid = c.gid 
FROM counties c 
where c.name = s.county;
```

This assumes that `counties.name` and `sites.county` are both unique.

Comment: You were missing an alias ;-)

Comment: That is indeed what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure why alias in the  `FROM` does not work in my case, I am using a Postgres 12. I have to use table name directly in the field reference to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE sites AS s
SET cgid = c.gid
FROM counties AS c
WHERE c.name = s.county
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `JOIN`.  Instead, you just need to connect the two tables in the `WHERE` clause:

```
UPDATE sites s
    SET cgid = c.gid 
    FROM counties c
    WHERE c.name = s.county;
```

Comment: Really weird: You have the earliest timestamp but I never saw you post.